# How can I get datetime in yyyy-MM-ddTHH24:mm:ss format from datetimepicker in Angular and send datetime to api?

Tags: angular-material, datetimepicker, date-format, get-request

I'm using Angular 12.2.4.
Thank you from now :)

in app.component.html

```
       <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="datepicker"
            placeholder="Tarih giriniz"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="datepicker"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #datepicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>    
      </div> 
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> Göster </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

in app.component.ts

The getgold function should get a string type date. I wrote the value "2021-07-30" myself to try. But I have to send the date I get from the user to this function. The api I will make a get request wants an input of type yyyy-MM-ddTHH24:mm:ss. Even if I can only send the date in yyyy-MM-dd format, my problem is actually solved. Because in the backend, I am editing the parameter as follows.
string body = "{ "PriceDate": "" + goldPriceDateTime + "T00:00:00+03:00"}";

```
ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.getGoldPrices("2021-07-30"); <-- must be date retrieved from datetimepicker
  }
  getGoldPrices(s: string){ 
    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:55000/api/GoldPriceDetail/'+ s).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.goldPrices = response;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't the date picker return a `Date` object? You can use `Date.toISOString()`

Comment: For example, when I use "Date.toISOString()" and enter 2021-07-30 in Datepicker, it returns 2021-07-29T21:00:00.000Z. I think there is a change in the timezone part. In addition, the format 020-08-14T00:00:00+03:00 is required.